# Merge Cells in multiple tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new in this but I'm trying to merge 3 cells on the second row in multiple tables on a word document, but I always receive the same error: 5941 The requested meber of the collection does not exist
Can someone help me to see where is the problem?

```
Sub add_tabl_rows()

 Dim tbl As Word.Table
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    tbl.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitContent

    tbl.Rows.Add BeforeRow:=tbl.Rows(2)

Dim cel1, cel2 As Word.Cell
     Set cel1 = tbl.Cell(2, 1)
     Set cel2 = tbl.Cell(2, 3)

    cel1.Merge MergeTo:=cel2

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that every table has those dimensions? Does every table have two rows?

Comment: If your table has less than three columns, your code will not work and gives the error you describe. How many columns do you have?

Comment: I have 40 tables, but 2 of them have 2columns. so that is the problem. thanks